# Dynamic social media buttons - reducing http requests and validation errors

Tags: javascript, facebook, validation, twitter, social-networking

I use the following code on a couple of sites I manage to add dynamic social media buttons.

Between them they add three javascript http requests and invalid code to every page. Though I appreciate these are all loading from a CDN they're adding to the already heavy load on one of the sites pages and the invalidity grates on me.

Is there any way to reduce the number of requests, or force that piece of code to load last and/or clean up the validity issues without breaking the scripts.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<div>
<ul> 
    <li> 
        <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/username" data-send="true" data-layout="button_count" data-width="100" data-show-faces="false"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a style="color: #777;" href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="horizontal" data-via="twittername">Tweet</a><script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="https://twitter.com/justicecampaign" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="true">Follow @twittername</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>
        <g:plusone size="medium"></g:plusone>
    </li>
</ul>   
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing you can do is move these scripts to the end of the `<body>` or add the `defer` attribute to the `script` tags for Twitter and Google+. Browsers halt parsing and rendering of a page while it downloads and executes JavaScript, so having third-party scripts in the middle of your HTML is not recommended as your page will be at the mercy of those third-party networks. If any of them are experiencing delays, your page will feel it. Moving these scripts to the bottom ensures that your content, which is the most important, is parsed and rendered first.

As for reducing requests, you could try downloading and combining those third-party scripts into a single script, eliminating two requests. The down-side is you won't get the latest versions of the scripts as they're updated, unless you proactively monitor and re-combine them.

I can't really speak on invalidity as I haven't looked into it much for these specific scripts.

Comment: Is there any way to force that section of code to load after the rest of the page?